# running a simple code Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop

I am running a simple code of MapReduce and am getting the following error:

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: Test.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:133)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)`
```

Some details of the problem:

My hadoop version is 0.20.
I have set  `new JobConf(Statecount.class)` where `Statecount.class` is the class from which I am running this job. What do I have to do to resolve this error?

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that the Test.jar file is not corrupted?

Comment: what does `jar -tvf Test.jar` show as a result?

Comment: Probably unrelated but is the mismatch `JobConf(Statecounte.class)` vs `Statecount.class` (notice the extra `e` in the `JobConf` just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run a jar named Test.jar in the java program RunJar?
If so please remember that any local path used could only be the on the name node.

Answer (score 0):

- check that the hadoop user (usually 'hadoop') have permission to this file
- sometimes hadoop need that some files will be on the HDFS and not in your file system.